# Sharepoint 2013 Search REST API return lack of result with exact phrase querytext

Tags: search, search-results, rest

In sharepoint foundation 2013 search REST API. I used double quotes to find exact phrases in document content which was attached in my sharepoint list item.

```
"/_api/search/query?querytext='\"" + query + "\" +ContentTypeId:0x01001CD4BA6C8A8343E7B733A0A8CA5A5D3D*'"
```

I have 3 pdf files which contain the phrase "Die anschließend aufgeführten Rollenbeschreibungen geben". However when I search with query = "Die anschließend aufgeführten Rollenbeschreibungen geben", I only get 1 result. But if I removed one word "geben" in query then I get 3 results.

If I removed the quote (not find exact phrases) in code or use the Sharepoint OOTB searchbox then It returned me 3 results. how strange it is???

Is there another way to search exactly phrase without add quote???

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried setting the TrimDuplicates variable to false?

Comment: Hi Robert, I tried but it does not work. 

if I remove the quote, is there another way to search exactly phrase???